# vtables and this pointer

Tags: c++, gcc, this, vtable, abi

I was trying to learn some more about the inner workings of vtables and vpointers, so I decided to try to access the vtable directly using some tricks. I created two classes, `Base` and `Derv`, each having two `virtual` functions (`Derv` overriding those of `Base`).

```
class Base
{
    int x;
    int y;

    public:
        Base(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}

        virtual void foo() { cout << "Base::foo(): x = " << x << '\n'; }    
        virtual void bar() { cout << "Base::bar(): y = " << y << '\n'; }
};

class Derv: public Base
{
    int x;
    int y;

    public:
        Derv(int x_, int y_) : Base(x_, y_), x(x_), y(y_) {}

        virtual void foo() { cout << "Derived::foo(): x = " << x << '\n'; }
        virtual void bar() { cout << "Derived::bar(): y = " << y << '\n'; }
};
```

Now, the compiler adds a vtable pointer to each class, occupying the first 4 bytes (32 bits) in memory. I accessed this pointer by casting the address of an object to a `size_t*`, since the pointer points to another pointer of size `sizeof(size_t)`. The virtual functions can now be accessed by indexing the vpointer, and casting the result to a function pointer of the appropriate type. I encapsulated these steps in a function:

```
template <typename T>
void call(T *ptr, size_t num)
{
    typedef void (*FunPtr)();

    size_t *vptr = *reinterpret_cast<size_t**>(ptr);
    FunPtr fun = reinterpret_cast<FunPtr>(vptr[num]);

    //setThisPtr(ptr);      added later, see below!
    fun();
}
```

When one of the memberfunctions are called this way, e.g. `call(new Base(1, 2), 0)` to call Base::foo(), it is hard to predict what will happen, since they are called without a `this`-pointer. I solved this by adding a little templatized function, knowing that g++ stores the `this`-pointer in the `ecx` register (this however forces me to compile with the `-m32` compiler flag):

```
template <typename T>
void setThisPtr(T *ptr)
{  
    asm ( mov %0, %%ecx;" :: "r" (ptr) );
}
```

Uncommenting the `setThisPtr(ptr)` line in the snippet above now makes it a working program:

```
int main()
{
    Base* base = new Base(1, 2);
    Base* derv =  new Derv(3, 4);

    call(base, 0); // "Base::foo(): x = 1" 
    call(base, 1); // "Base::bar(): y = 2"
    call(derv, 0); // "Derv::foo(): x = 3"
    call(derv, 1); // "Derv::bar(): y = 4"
}
```

I decided to share this, since in the process of writing this little program I gained more insight in how vtables work and it might help others in understanding this material a little better. 
However I still have some questions:
1. Which register is used (gcc 4.x) to store the this-pointer when compiling a 64-bit binary? I tried all 64-bit registers as documented here: http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/asmregs.html
2. When/how is the this-pointer set? I suspect that the compiler sets the this pointer on each function call through an object in a similar way as to how I just did it. Is this the way polymorphism actually works? (By setting the this-pointer first, then calling the virtual function from the vtable?).

Comment: This is a bit long for a typical SO question.  Can you work on condensing this down to the core issue?  (In fact, is any of your post directly relevant to the questions at the end?)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Well it is for me, since this is how I came to these questions. The second question asks if the compiler uses a similar methodology to enable polymorphism, so I think I should include my own. Would you suggest another medium through which I could share this information and ask the questions?

Comment: You should ask the questions here, with just enough context for them to make sense (it doesn't sound like you need *any* context for these particular questions).  If you want to share stuff that you've discovered, you should probably set up a blog...

Comment: Try this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10900/Polymorphism-in-C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux x86_64, and I believe other UNIX-like OSes, function calls follow the [System V ABI (AMD64)](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), which itself follows the [IA-64 C++ ABI](http://www.codesourcery.com/cxx-abi/) for C++.  Depending on the method's type, the `this` pointer is either passed implicitly through first argument or the second argument (when the return value has non-trivial copy constructor or destructor, it must live as a temporary on stack, and the first argument is implicitly a pointer to that space); otherwise, virtual method calls are identical to function calls in C (integer/pointer arguments in `%rdi`, `%rsi`, `%rdx`, `%rcx`, `%r8`, `%r9`, overflowing to stack; integer/pointer return in `%rax`; floats in `%xmm0`-`%xmm7`; etc.).  Virtual method dispatch works by looking up a pointer in the vtable then calling it just like a non-virtual method.

I'm less familiar with Windows x64 conventions, but I believe it to be similar in that C++ method calls follow the exact same structure as C function calls (which use different registers than on Linux), just with an implicit `this` argument first.

Comment: For Microsoft compatible C++ implementation, vtable is explained in introductory part of Don Box's Essential COM & (I've heard of another book Inside COM)